# can not read dataBaseURl project

Tags: javascript

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, push, onValue } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js";

var AppSettings = {
  dataBaseURL:
    "https://playgroung-e37ce-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/",
};
```

i gettinf   an  Error message in the conseol "ATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL. Be sure to include  a Project ID when calling firebase.initializeApp()"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you got is telling you to include the id of your project while calling the firebase.inititlizeApp(). You can try something like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, push, onValue } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  databaseURL: "YOUR_DATABASE_URL",
  projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "YOUR_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
  measurementId: "YOUR_MEASUREMENT_ID"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var AppSettings = {
  dataBaseURL:
    "https://playgroung-e37ce-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/",
};

const database = getDatabase(app, AppSettings.dataBaseURL);

// write your code ...
```